# How to avoid out of the memory issues of Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, memory, android-fragments, fragment, out-of-memory

What are the best practices to avoid out of memory issues in Android fragments?

Do I need to release the memory on fragment destroy?

Comment: Usually unneeded fragments should be garbage collected. Are you sure there are no memory leaks?

Comment: Use replace instead of add and do not add it in back stack as needed.

Comment: @Sprigg how to avoid memory leaks in the app? Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `replace` instead of `add`, unless you have a specific reason to add fragments.

`replace` removes all existing fragment from the layout with the passed resource id, before inserting a new fragment into the layout.

If there are currently no fragments assigned to the layout, it does exactly the same as `add`.

Comment: That is not always true as there are certain cases that add might be a better choice than Replace. E.g. When you are in a parent fragment and you add a child fragment for the user to choose some settings. When user selects settings and goes back is better experience for the user if the previous does not reload. Adding two light fragments most of the time should not cause memory issues.

Comment: If you add your fragment transactions to the backstack, the state of the parent fragment is saved and restored correctly. Even if you use replace.